# How to shuffle a linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I can't for the life of me figure out why this shuffle method isn't working:

```
public void deckShuffle(int shuffle) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int targetCard, cardValue, cardSuit;
    Card temp, card;

    for (int x = 0; x < shuffle; x++) {
    for(int y = 1; y < 52; y++) {
            targetCard = 51 - rand.nextInt(51);
            temp = getCard(targetCard);
            cardValue = temp.getCardValue();
            cardSuit = temp.getCardSuit();
            removeCard(targetCard);
            addLast(cardValue, cardSuit);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for remove card and add last:

```
public void removeCard(int index) {

    if (head.next == null || index < 1) {return;}

    if (count > 0 && index <= count) {
        Card current = head;

        for (int x = 0; x < index; x++) {
            current = current.next;
        }

        current.next = current.next.next;
        count--;
    }
}




public void addLast(int cardValue, int cardSuit) {
    Card temp = new Card(cardValue, cardSuit, null);        
    Card current = head; // POINTER

    while (current.next != null) {
        current = current.next;
    }

    current.next = temp;
    count++;
}
```

I am trying to figure out why the code won't work. When i run a method to print a deck of 52 cards and shuffle it, the cards all show up as 2s of hearts. I know it isn't my build deck method because I tested that before writing the shuffle method.

I figured it out guys. My remove card method wasn't working properly but now it is so the deck shuffles properly. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: why do you have 2 loops?

Comment: info is not enough. if you want to implement shuffle yourself, i don't think linked list is a good container.

Comment: What is `head`? It doesn't seem to be a normal card since it doesn't look like you can remove it, and `addLast()` assumes you already have one (if head is null, it'll throw a NPE).

Comment: Please provide the `Card` class as well as the `getCard` method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `Collections.shuffle` method?

For more info maybe you should post your Card class? Then at least someone can try to run the code if they feel like it.

Comment: Not allowed to for our class... :/

Comment: Ok, but please post your Card class then. We can't see what next() does now.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek there is no `next` method, but variable. it's a confusing naming.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm so used to reading scala nowadays. I'd recommend using getters/setters so you can change the implementation later on without breaking things.

Comment: This is basically something we are doing in our class to learn about linked lists. The method itself is supposedly very close to what it is supposed to be, but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Alright. Well it's still easier if you would post the contents of your Card class, then someone can try to debug it if they feel like it. It's a bit hard to read what's going on to me.

Comment: OK sorry I'm pretty new to this:

Comment: public class Card {
        Card next;   // Link to the NEXT card in the list
        int cardValue, cardSuit; //Card values 1-14 correspond to their respective cards. Suits 0 - 3 correspond to H , S, D, C. 
    
    public Card() {
        next = null;
        cardValue = 0;
        cardSuit = 0;
    }

Comment: No worries :) but you can edit this in your original post so everyone can find it. Also I don't see anywhere where the count variable is declared so I would also add that.

Comment: well i cant figure out how to post code in comments.

Comment: That's because you're not supposed to post code in comments.  Since you're the OP, you should edit your question to add the code.

Comment: Ok. I had to leave my computer for a while but I can post the extra code later tonight. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (head.next == null || index < 1) {return;}
```

i don't think it's what you want. you should want:

```
if (head == null) return;
```

the original version make removing not working as it says when there is only one card in the deck.

or even delete this line if `head` is a fixed linked list header instance.

Comment: I think this is ok because the head will always be null so that would always break. It's checking to see if there is a card after the head.

Comment: are you sure? what if random number is 0? why do you prevent the first card from being removed?

Comment: The goal is to have it so that the random number can never be 0. The first card is at index 1, the head is just a placeholder without card value.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
        targetCard = 51 - rand.nextInt(51);
```

be

```
        targetCard = rand.nextInt(52-y);
```

though this wouldn't cause the issue you describe, I believe you may have an issue with the other parts of the system

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I'll change that.